A question about partial proof in RSA CTF problems
e=65537
m2 = bytes_to_long(flag2)
p = getPrime(1024)
q = getPrime(1024)
n = p * q
c = pow(m2, e, n)
hint = pow(2023 * p + 114514, q, n)
print("n=",n)
print("c=",c)
print("hint=",hint)

I saw on WP that Hint is like this:
hint = pow(2023 * p + 114514, q, n)

=>

hint = (2023 * p + 114514)^q mod p

hint = 114514^q + k1 * p

114514^q = hint - k1*p

(114514^q)^p = (hint - k1*p)^p

114514^n = p*(.....) + hint^p

=>

114514^n = hint^p mod p = hint

and
p = GCD(pow(114514,nn,nn) - hint,nn)

i don't konw why
hint = pow(2023 * p + 114514, q, n)

=>

hint = (2023 * p + 114514)^q mod p

I think the proof process is not rigorous. Can someone provide a more rigorous proof

The question's hint = (2023 * p + 114514)^q mod p is not intended to mean $\text{hint},=,(2023,p+114514)^q\bmod p$. It's intended to mean $\text{hint}\equiv(2023,p+114514)^q\pmod p$. The former would imply $0\le\text{hint}<p$, which is false. The later does not. To prove the later, use that $x\equiv y\pmod{u,v}\implies x\equiv y\pmod u$. Recall the later is a notation for: $x-y$ is a multiple of $u$.

thank you ,i know
